# How to properly force https and www on multisite with Apache HTAccess

Tags: multisite, htaccess, domain, ssl, https

I have a wordpress multisite in network mode via wp multi network plugin.

I've been trying to use `.htaccess` rules to force all urls to be `https://www.`

eg:

- `https://domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`
- `http://domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`
- `http://www.domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`

I've found these variations online but I'm not sure what would be the cleanest way to do this?

```
## force HTTPS and www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!^www\.)^(.+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(dev|www)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,L]
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(dev|www)\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,L]
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First one of your variations is the cleanest.
You can test your htaccess rewrite rules here:
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Important thing about **R=301**, this means the redirection is permanent.